# "Sub Controllers" in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am developing an application with the Zend Frameworks.

I currently have the Controller admin, which has its appropriate actions

I have the action "Users", and and I would like to be able to make this its own controller, so all the relevant actions are under their own class

```
Admin {
    Users {
        Add
        Delete
        Import
    }
}
```

Comment: This where you would use a module. Module Admin controller Users...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Restructure your code using modules. `Admin` should become a [module](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.modular.html). Inside the Admin module you should have the controller Users. This controller has the actions add, delete and import.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to the whole MVC arch so this is all new to me. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

I think what you really need is an Action Helper, since add/delete/import "actions" are more or less ubiquitous.